# Laravel 5 Elixir takes too long to compile LESS

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-5, gulp-watch, laravel-elixir

I'm currently experiancing a slow down in my development workflow, it is taking around 3-4s for my less to compile and then version, this is causing much annoyance. I would like to 'split' my watcher down so that it is only compiling the changed files, I would wondering if this was possible in Elixir without going to core Gulp?

Currently I have:

```
mix.less([
        'app.less',
        'login.less',
        'till.less'
    ])
    .version([
        "css/app.css",
        "css/login.css"
    ]);
```

I have tried splitting this down into multiple pipes, but it appears to overwrite and only do the last task:

```
mix.less([
        'app.less',
        'login.less'
    ])
    .less(['till.css'])
    .version([
        "css/app.css",
        "css/login.css"
    ]);
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting long build times by gulp, but by using the --production flag it cut down my build time by about half the time, but take note that it also compresses the output. May be this will work for you also.